# Google Play Services running on Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services

Adding Google Play Services lib (v.7327000) to my app, it works well on real devices but *Activity* crashes and I get error on running emulator (Google API 21/22, tried Nexus4/5/10) like this:

*"E/OpenGLRenderer(2560): Could not allocate texture for layer (fbo=1 2560x1326)"*

Tried with Android Studio (selective lib) and Eclipse (library project).
Does anyone know a solution ?